# Why are the camera and lamp objects appearing in the OpenGL render?

Tags: rendering, opengl

I am new to blender. First time I tried rendering the animation using Cycles render it worked fine. After that I tried OpenGl render, and after that this problem has started. The objects including the camera and light(lamp) in the 3d viewport are being rendered in the images.
I don't know if its a feature or a bug. Please help.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Could you post some screenshots of your scene and renders? Perhaps upload your blend file. Which button are you pressing to render? You should use the one in the properties window, not the one in the 3D view toolbar. Also make sure Cycles render is set as the current renderer, not the game engine o internal

Comment: Cycles materials don't get along with GLSL materials. At all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL render renders what you see in the viewport to a texture:

[image: OpenGL render]

In the viewport, go to the Properties panel (N) and check "Only Render" in "Display".

[image: Only render]

OpenGL render again, and:

[image: OpenGL render "only render"]

So, yes, it's a feature.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Sorry for bothering you for such a small thing and i figured out that i must be in Default viewport to make it kinda work as i wanted. Kudos :D